# Java - Compiler parses unicode source file incorrectly

Tags: java, unicode, compilation

Consider the following scenario

example.txt:

```
ÄäÖöÜü
```

Java source:

```java
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("example.txt");
     InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

    String stringLoadedFromOutside = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String stringConstructedInside = "ÄäÖöÜü";

    System.out.println("string constant: " + stringConstructedInside);
    System.out.println("loaded string: " + stringLoadedFromOutside);
    System.out.println("equal: " + stringConstructedInside.equals(stringLoadedFromOutside));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both files are encoded in the UTF-8.

This outputs:

```
string constant: Ã„Ã¤Ã–Ã¶ÃœÃ¼
loaded string: ÄäÖöÜü
equal: false
```

How can I prevent the compiler from turning my unicode in the source into the wrong string?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. `stringConstructedInside` isn't what you say it was in the source. The encoding of the file makes no difference. You're changing it at some step.

Comment: @tagir I don't think this is a duplicate. OP thinks that is the solution, but the problem is elsewhere. Some step in their build phase is changing the source code to contain a different value, not `ÄäÖöÜü`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if you have an idea what's going on, feel free to reopen (I guess your rep permits you) and write a new answer. As OP himself answers that `-encoding` solved his problem, it looks like a duplicate for me. (Side note: sometimes I dislike this golden-badge feature to be the only responsible person for duplicate mark. Why can't I just add one of five votes like it was before?..)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler assumes the system's standard charset, and the UTF-8 is apparently not the system's standard charset for you.

When using `javac` directly:

```
javac -encoding utf8 MySourceFile.java
```

When using gradle, you can use:

- For all java compiler tasks:

  ```
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      options.encoding = 'utf8'
  }
  ```
- For a single task:

  ```
  compileJava.options.encoding = 'utf8'
  ```

Now the code would output:

```
string constant: ÄäÖöÜü
loaded string: ÄäÖöÜü
equal: true
```